# Contact Form Laravel 5.4 Email Error

Tags: php, html, email, laravel-5, contact-form

I am getting  an error while clicking on the send button from Contact Form. I am using Laravel 5.4. Please help me to resolve this error.

I already cleared the the cache but still getting this error...php artisan config:cache

**Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required**

Here is my Mail function...

```
public function getContactUsForm(){
        $data = Input::all();
        $rules = array (
            'fullname' => 'Required',
            'email' => 'Required|Email',
            'subject' => 'Required',
            'message' => 'Required'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make ($data, $rules);
        if ($validator -> passes()){

            Mail::send('contactmail', $data, function($message) use ($data)
            {
                $message->from($data['email'] , $data['fullname']);
                $message->to('myemail', 'myname')->subject('Contact Request');

            });
            Session::put('flash_message', 'Thank you for contacting us – we will get back to you soon!');
            return redirect()->back();
        }else{
            return Redirect::to('/contactus')->withErrors($validator);
        }
    }
```

This is my mail.php file

```
 <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myemail'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'sendername'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('myemail'),

    'password' => env('********'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: this is because you are trying to send email from localhost.

Comment: i think this is not a problem...i had done mail testing on localhost before.

Comment: with laravel? or with another framework?

Comment: with laravel 5.2....right now working with 5.4

Comment: are you using ssl or tls for encryption?

Comment: using tls for encryption...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set your email provider in `.env` file?

Change your `session::put` to `session::flash`

**Update:**

Try this one in your function

```
    public function postcontactus(Request $request) {
          $this->validate($request, array(
            'fullname' => 'Required',
            'email' => 'Required|Email',
            'subject' => 'Required',
            'messagetext' => 'Required'
          ));

          $data = array(
            'fullname' => $request->fullname,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'messagetext' => $request->messagetext,
          );

          Mail::send('contactmail', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to('Your Email');
            $message->subject($data['subject']);
          });
Session::put('flash_message', 'Thank you for contacting us – we will get back to you soon!');
      return redirect()->back();

    }
```

Note: you are using `message` to pass users message in email which is not allowed because laravel itself using message method you should use another name such as `messagetext` that I used or anything else you like.

Also change it in your blade:

```
{{Form::label('messagetext', 'Message')}}
{{Form::textarea('messagetext', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])}}
```

Example of `.env` file settings:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I am using mailtrap and i have given the email providers in .env but still i am getting the error

Comment: Here is my error
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError f13sm2020065pfj.127 - gsmtp